# Let $F$ be a field and let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $F[x]$ that is reducible over $F$. Prove that $⟨ f(x) ⟩ $ is not a prime ideal in $F[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

An ideal is prime whenever $ab\in A \rightarrow a\in A$ or $b\in A$.

I am a little confused on how to get started, and how exactly the elements of ideal even look like. If somebody could give me a hint or two that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $f(x)$ is reducible, then $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ for some polynomials $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ with degrees strictly less than that of $f(x)$.

Certainly $f(x) = g(x)h(x) \in \langle f(x) \rangle \ \ $  ...

---

To answer your other question, elements of $\langle f(x) \rangle$ will be of the form $f(x)r(x)$ for any polynomial $r(x) \in F[x]$. I'd encourage you to go back to the definition in your textbook and confirm that this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is reducible, we can write $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ where $ deg f(x)\geq deg g(x),deg h(x) \geq 1.$ $g(x)h(x)$ belongs to this ideal, but neither of them does!